# Are there any charactersequenzes that might prevent php mail from sending?

Tags: php, email

I have a PHP script that runs as a cronjob. At the end of execution I want to send an email to me, with the script status.

```
mail('myemail@address.com', 'Cronjob Status', $ret);
```

Returns true, but no mail is received.

```
mail('myemail@address.com', 'Cronjob Status', 'Test Mail'.$ret);
```

Works fine.

$ret is something like

```
"Time 4 Scriptexecution: 5s\nFound: xxx of this\nRepaired: yyy of that"
```

What is wrong with my first mail statement? Is there anything that $ret might contain, that explains this?

Comment: `var_dump($ret);` in both cases and compare the output.

Comment: These kind of messages are likely to be classified as spam. You should check your spam folder (if any).

Comment: Those two lines are directly after each other so $ret should have the exact same value.

Comment: There is no mail in my spam folder, it is disabled (at my side at least)